# How do I stop Visual Studio's 'Publish Web Site' from publishing my _ReSharper folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

It's really quite annoying as they are not part of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio Web Deployment addin lets you exclude folders and more. 
[VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx)
[VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en)

Also a decent writeup on the [Web Deployment addin](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/VisualStudio/126_Web_Deployment_Project_for_Visual_Studio_2005_and_2008.aspx)

Comment: This looks like a much more powerful way to do deployment, but how can I configure it to ignore my _ReSharper files?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is really old, but maybe someone else will be helped with my reply.

I found the solution here: http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=137

Basically, add these lines to the bottom of your web deployment project file above the  tab.

Just put your folder or file in there too and it will not be copied over.