# How do I exclude a particular folder from the copying process in a Web Deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, web-deployment-project

I am suing VS 2005 and a Web Deployment project. The problem is that the build process takes a very long time because the deployment process copies my images folder to the deployment directory. The images folder is small in size but has thousands of files. I want to keep the images in my development folder so that I can see if the linking to the images in the HTML works. However I never upload the images because they are already there. So I am ideally wanting to exclude that folder from the deployment process.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318/how-do-i-stop-visual-studios-publish-web-site-from-publishing-my-resharper-fo) post mentions an addin ([Web Deployment addin](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/VisualStudio/126_Web_Deployment_Project_for_Visual_Studio_2005_and_2008.aspx)) that should allow you to exclude items from the build process.

You can also go about excluding items by manually editing the Web Deployment project file. Look under the **Customizing Web Deployment Projects** heading here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx