# asp.net publish only pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 web project. There are lots of images on images folder. apprx. 1.5GB size.

Everytime I want to publish the project, it takes 35minutes. I dont want to publish folders. I only want to publish pages.

Im using shared web hosting.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `images` folder from your project.

Publishing a website will publish any folders that are part of the project, so removing the folder from the project will ensure it will not be published.

This will add a burden to maintaining the site and ensuring you have all the images on your development environment.

You can still have it in source control if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Publish your site to a local directory, and then just FTP up those items that you need - exclude the images.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is publish time. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack - but i imagine the slow bit of this is sending the images to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links would help you.

[How do I stop Visual Studio's 'Publish Web Site' from publishing my _ReSharper folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318/how-do-i-stop-visual-studios-publish-web-site-from-publishing-my-resharper-fo)

http://forums.asp.net/p/1413126/3105180.aspx